# Can't log in to Stack Exchange: redirecting doesn't finish

Tags: bug, login

I have been a Stack Overflow user for months. However, when I tried to log in today, I was unable to log in. Whenever I try to log in, the website says:

> Completing Log in. It'll be automatically redirected

However, it's taking forever to get redirected and complete the login. Hence, I created a second account to ask for the solution. Is it because Stack Overflow changed its JS?

I'm using Google Chrome version 96, and the browser isn't showing error messages. Also, I can't upvote, accept answers, or comment on a question.

- JS isn't disabled
- My main account is [MsBonniePython](https://stackexchange.com/users/21532038/msbonniepython)

---

Now I can log in to my account but I still can't upvote, accept answers, or comment on a question. My main account has more than 15 reputation on Math Stack Exchange, where I'm trying to upvote some answers.

---

I'm not using any plugins and my js is enabled

Comment: What is your browser? Do you see any error messages in the console? Are you running any plugins or userscripts?

Comment: Maybe Javascript is disabled. All user interaction, including login, is disabled in that case.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the browser cache or deleting SE/SO cookies?

Comment: Logging in on Stack Overflow shouldn't be redirecting you anywhere. Can you link to your main account, please?

Comment: @AdamLear the OP provided their main account (which I added a link to) (pinging you directly in case you didn't follow the question or missed its update)

Comment: if you're trying to comment or upvote on Stack Overflow then [your main account](https://stackexchange.com/users/21532038/msbonniepython?tab=accounts) is currently lacking the privileges to do so. Upvoting comes at 15 rep, commenting at 50 (except for your own posts). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/why-do-we-need-50-reputation-to-make-comments

Comment: Could you answer the parts of my comment about plugins and userscripts?

Comment: Okay, can you answer about userscripts? While it may be easy to assume we assume you don't have any, we can't be sure and it could be relevant.

Comment: Sorry your question makes no sense now. You can login, but can't perform actions on Stack Overflow because you lack the required reputation. I don't understand what is the problem now. If you think your reputation on the main site affects Stack Overflow privileges, you're wrong, it does not. Each site in Stack Exchange has its own reputation.

Comment: @Shadow The OP says nothing about performing actions on *Stack Overflow*. They say they cannot upvote, accept answers, and comment on *Math.SE*. The account has 75 reputation there, which should be enough.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek "I have been a ***Stack Overflow user*** for months. However, when I tried to log in today, I was unable to log in" - the question is about their Stack Overflow account, which doesn't have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: @Shadow That initial sentence does not mention any failed upvote actions etc., and it seems to just use Stack Overflow as a synonym for Stack Exchange. (There is common login anyway, so it’s not wrong.) The specific description of the currently persisting problem of the user says “Now I can log in to my account but I still can't **upvote**, **accept answers**, or **comment** on a question. My main account has more than 15 reputation on **Math Stack Exchange**, **where** I'm trying to **upvote** some answers.”